# How to print array and values from new cycle to next rows

Tags: arrays, excel, loops, vba

this is part of my code that i am working with and I have one problem. I have array with values (masyvas) and i started new loop to find other values by using masyvas(i,1) values and after that i need that new values would be printed in masyvas(i,2) and i need to group them. It need to look like this:

991988  Gaz.duon.sk"Giros"gaiv.g.1,5L   5_PETØFLAT1,5

```
        PALINK
```

117388  Silp.gaz.nat.min.v"Tiche'1,5L 5_PETØFLAT1,5

```
       PALINK
       RIMI LIETUVA
       ŠIAULIŲ TARA
```

111388  Gaz.nat.min.v"Tiche" 1,5L pet 5_PETØFLAT1,5

```
       PALINK
       AIBĖS LOGISTIKA
       AIBĖS LOGISTIKA
       RIMI LIETUVA
       ŠIAULIŲ TARA
```

[How it looks now from marked 1 it goes wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqKyL.jpg)

[Data sheet where i get array values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQmM7.png)

Here is part of my code where i have this problem now it prints new values next to masyvas(i,2) but not below as I need.

```
lastrow2 = Sheets("lapas").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

rub = lastrow2
cub = 3

ReDim masyvas(1 To rub, 1 To cub)
For i = 1 To rub
   For j = 1 To cub
      masyvas(i, j) = Sheets("lapas").Cells(i, j).Value 'array gets values from filtered data in AKCIJOS sheet
   Next
Next

Sheets("lapas").Range("A1:C100").Clear



For i = 1 To rub Step 1
Set rng2 = grafikas.Cells(6 + h, 2)

    prekeskodas = masyvas(i, 1)


        For m = 2 To lastrow
            If akcijos.Cells(m, 8) >= laikas And akcijos.Cells(m, 8) <= laikas2 Then
                If prekeskodas = akcijos.Cells(m, 4) Then

                grafikas.Cells(7 + r, 2).EntireRow.Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                grafikas.Cells(7 + r, 3) = akcijos.Cells(m, 3)

                r = r + 1
                h = r
                End If

            End If
         Next m

    For j = 1 To cub Step 1

      rng2.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value = masyvas(i, j)

    Next


Next
```

Comment: Please edit the question correctly, so we can see what your desired output is. From what you posted it's hard to say what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any screenshot of your data, so it's hard to say what exactly is your problem and desired output, but try the code below. I marked changed lines.

```
For i = 1 To rub
prekeskodas = masyvas(i, 1)

For m = 2 To lastrow
    If akcijos.Cells(m, 8) >= laikas And akcijos.Cells(m, 8) <= laikas2 Then
        If prekeskodas = akcijos.Cells(m, 4) Then

           'masyvas(i, 2) = masyvas(i, 2) & akcijos.Cells(m, 3)
           masyvas(i, m) = masyvas(i, m) & akcijos.Cells(m, 3) '<------

        End If
    End If
Next

For j = 1 To cub

    rng2.Offset(j - 1, i - 1).Value = masyvas(i, j) '<-----

Next
Next
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): structure of data in "Akcijos" sheet and full code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Stalkeris BTW, did you try [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting/8020/debugger-locals-window#t=201708010630492808329) your code?

Comment: I provided more code and image how my data sheet looks like and 
I tried debugging.